# Grep using caret symbol (^) to match beginning of line is not working

Tags: macos, shell, grep, zsh

Hello I am using zsh on macOS,

When i do

```
>> echo 'abcdefghi' | grep -o -E '^.{3}'                        
abc
def
ghi
```

I expected the result to be just `abc`, does anyone knows what happens, what have I misunderstood ? How can i get only first match?

Comment: It is a bug, see https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166842

Comment: You could install on the Mac the [Gnu Tools](https://ryanparman.com/posts/2019/using-gnu-command-line-tools-in-macos-instead-of-freebsd-tools/). They don't exhibit this bug.